# Apache Spark number of executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have Spark app on databricks, running it on cluster of 32 nodes, 16 cores each and 30gb memory. I wanted to change some session configurations but no matter what i change, I cannot make more executors then 32(as seen on executors page spark ui)? These configs i've changed:

```
spark.executor.instances
spark.executor.memory 
spark.executor.cores
```

As i read, max number of concurrent tasks should be 5, so I wanted to make 4 executors per node, each using 4 cores...total number of executors - 128. How can i do that?

Kind regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

For the Spark build with the latest version, we can set the parameters: `--executor-cores` and `--total-executor-cores` . the total executor would be `total-executor-cores/executor-cores`

Try this one:

```
spark-submit  --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 4 --total-executor-cores 512
```

Comment: Hi. Problem is, as I know, you can not use spark submit in databricks notebook.

Comment: You can use spark-submit in batch mode .i.e with Jobs cluster